# Adding custom font error with Xcode 13 with ("Fonts provided by application")

Tags: swift, xcode, uifont

I followed nearly every tutorial and stack overflow questions and still couldn't get my fonts to work.

1. I downloaded Montserrat font from Google fonts
2. I added the folder to my project with Copy items checked and targets checked
3. I added the fonts I want under "Fonts provided by application" and added the names
4. I still cannot find and use my font after printing the family names out

Any ideas what could go wrong?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: please add again your fonts directory into your project don't select folder reference, just select create group and make check add to targets

Comment: sadly, it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: font extension must also be entered. But I didn't solve it. I'm using xcode 13.3 and I'm finally going to try reinstalling xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "PostScript name" that can be obtained by installing the font on the mac and obtaining information specifically about the font in question in "Font Book"

Answer (score 0):

Do you check `target membership` at each font?
If you checked, init font with `UIFont(name: "montserrat", size: size)!`